# Batch file error handling

Tags: batch-file, error-handling, network-programming

I am very new to batch files, but I have a fair amount of experience in other programming.  I have a batch file that runs two polling applications that allow a remote server to indirectly communicate with another computer on my network.  The poller accessing the computer on my network frequently returns an error 1509 (multiple connections to the same computer with the same credentials); however the command line ignores this and continues processing as though that poller ran normally.  Is there a way to interrupt the batch in the event of a specific network error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
If errorlevel 1509 if not errorlevel 1510 echo Error 1509 occured
```

The error level test is always that number or higher.

Comment: So is there a way, after executing code responding to the error, to reset the errorlevel to 0?

Answer (score 0):

I've lost my logon. So to reply to your followup query the errorlevel is set after every Windows command. Third party programs do what they want.

Don't try to reset it yourself. Windows also puts the errorlevel into `%errorlevel%`. If you mess with this it will stop doing it.

`If errorlevel n` is always reliable unlike `%errorlevel%`.

Comment: That fixes problems we've been having for years here!  I really appreciate your help.  I've been searching the internet for days, and while I've found plenty of threads addressing the errorlevel variable, I haven't seen any that address how to use it in any useful way other than to return it.  For processes like mine that run overnight, returning the error code does not fix the problem that the process failed.